# Angular Test tutorials on Jasmine website not working

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I just started practice tests on angular-seed app based on Jasmine. When using the first test example found on [pivotal.github.io/jasmine/](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/?) it fails on my app.

**Test example code:**

```
describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

but passes on [tryjasmine.com](http://tryjasmine.com/)

I did a test for content and views/partials, they pass. but the one on the jasmine site fails. Am I missing something or is there some config I need to setup?

**Karma.conf.js file:**

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/lib/angular/angular.js',
  'app/lib/angular/angular-*.js',
  'test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/js/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = true;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
  suite: 'unit'
};
```

**Karma-e2e.conf.js file:**

```
basePath = '../';

files = [
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
  ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
  'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];

autoWatch = false;

browsers = ['Chrome'];

singleRun = true;

proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8000/'
};

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test_out/e2e.xml',
  suite: 'e2e'
};
```

Comment: Are you using Karma. If so please put your settings of karma.conf.js with your question.

Comment: Does the test fail?  Or does it not run at all?  Do you see the Jasmine results screen?  I am guessing that you haven't initialized Jasmine.  Are you including this code? http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-The_Runner_and_Reporter

Comment: @BKM added the karma.conf code

Comment: @D'loDeProjuicer configuration file is fine

Comment: Did you run the runner.html in the browser. What did it say?

Comment: @BrianGenisio the test runs but fails... BKM runner.html shows the result set.. the test for views pass.

Comment: @BrianGenisio I discovered one of the files needed for Jasmine to be initialized has a problem.

on the Runner and Reporter section of the doc there is:
`document.querySelector('.version').innerHTML = jasmineEnv.versionString();`

browser console throws an error about the `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to  http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-The_Runner_and_Reporter on the Runner and Reporter section of the doc there is:

`document.querySelector('.version').innerHTML = jasmineEnv.versionString();`

browser console throws an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

after looking around I found other examples dont have that line. I used the example in tuts+ http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-your-javascript-with-jasmine/

On that tutorial there is `SpecRunner.html`  it has that block of code without `document.querySelector('.version').innerHTML = jasmineEnv.versionString();`

and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You're using old karma's configuration style. I see two options

1) you have quite old karma version,

2) you are trying to run new karma on the old configuration style.

You should try to upgrade karma to the newest version and migrate your configuration to the new style, see: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: I updated the configs, however that was not the problem. But thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can comment:

```
document.querySelector('.version').innerHTML = jasmineEnv.versionString();
```

Or you can add in your body:

```
<div class='version'></div>
```